# how to get integer as user Input which later be used as a parameter in Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, kivy

I am a newbie in kivy and I'm making a workout list. I collect the number of sets the user wants and on the next window, I want user to input the amount of repetition in each set. To get user Input I used this

Python code:

```
    ActiveExerciseSet = None
    class AddWorkoutWidget(Screen):
        exercise_set = ObjectProperty("0")

        def AddExercise(self):
        ActiveExerciseSet = self.exercise_set.text
```

Kivy code:

```
<AddWorkoutWidget>
    exercise_set : exercise_set
            Label:
                text: "Number of sets "

            TextInput:
                id: exercise_set
                input_filter: 'int'
                multiline: False

            Button:
                text: 'Number of reps'
                on_press:root.AddExercise()
```

Now I want to use the number of sets as a loop parameter

```
class AddSetWidget(GridLayout,Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddSetWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)  # call grid layout parameters
        self.cols = int(ActiveExerciseSet)
        for I in self.col:
            pass
```

but I keep on getting *TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'*

is there any way to turn this into an integer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a logical error. Here's the thing

```
ActiveExerciseSet = None # this is a global variable
class AddWorkoutWidget(Screen):
    exercise_set = ObjectProperty("0")

    def AddExercise(self):
        ActiveExerciseSet = self.exercise_set.text #this creates a local variable within this function
```

so when you trigger this function, the global variable is still `None` where you thought you assigned it a value

```
class AddSetWidget(GridLayout,Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddSetWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)  # call grid layout parameters
        self.cols = int(ActiveExerciseSet)
        #this is looking for a local variable
        #and not the global variable
        for I in self.col:
            pass
```

Therefore, you get the error that it's a `NoneType` - which is correct as your Global Variable is assigned a value `None`

**The Solution**
In order to use/assign the value to a `global variable`, you need to use the keyword `global`

```
def AddExercise(self):
    global ActiveExerciseSet#reference to global variable
    ActiveExerciseSet = self.exercise_set.text


class AddSetWidget(GridLayout,Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddSetWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)  # call grid layout parameters
        global ActiveExerciseSet #reference to global variable
        self.cols = int(ActiveExerciseSet)
        for I in self.col:
            pass
```